# Is this a safe way to use ulid concurrently with other libraries too?

Tags: go, ulid

I'm trying to use for the first time the [ulid package](https://github.com/oklog/ulid).

In [their README](https://github.com/oklog/ulid#usage) they say:

> Please note that `rand.Rand` from the `math` package is *not* safe for concurrent use.
> Instantiate one per long living go-routine or use a `sync.Pool` if you want to avoid the potential contention of a locked `rand.Source` as its been frequently observed in the package level functions.

Can you help me understand what does this mean and **how to write SAFE code for concurrent use with libraries such [ent](https://github.com/ent/ent) or [gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen)**?

Example: I'm using the below code in my app to generate new IDs (sometimes even many of them in the same millisecond which is fine for `ulid`).

```golang
import (
  "math/rand"
  "time"

  "github.com/oklog/ulid/v2"
)

var defaultEntropySource *ulid.MonotonicEntropy

func init() {
  defaultEntropySource = ulid.Monotonic(rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())), 0)
}

func NewID() string {
  return ulid.MustNew(ulid.Timestamp(time.Now()), defaultEntropySource).String()
}
```

**Is this a safe way to use the package?**

Answer (score 3):

> Is this a safe way to use the package?

No, that sentence suggests that each rand.Source should be local to the goroutine, your `defaultEntropySource` rand.Source piece is potentially shared between multiple goroutines.

As documentated [New function](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/oklog/ulid/v2#New), you only need to make sure the entropy reader is safe for concurrent use, but [Monotonic](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/oklog/ulid/v2#Monotonic) is not. Here is a two ways of implementing the documentation suggestion:

Create a single rand.Source per call o NewID(), allocates a new entropy for each call to NewID

```
func NewID() string {
    defaultEntropySource := ulid.Monotonic(rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())), 0)
    return ulid.MustNew(ulid.Timestamp(time.Now()), defaultEntropySource).String()
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/L3NTGGR8wMg)

Like above but using sync.Pool to possible reuse previously allocated `rand.Source`s

```
var entropyPool = sync.Pool{
    New: func() any {
        entropy := ulid.Monotonic(rand.New(rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano())), 0)
        return entropy
    },
}

func NewID() string {
    e := entropyPool.Get().(*ulid.MonotonicEntropy)
    s := ulid.MustNew(ulid.Timestamp(time.Now()), e).String()
    entropyPool.Put(e)
    return s
}
```

[Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/JgnIH8k9krI)

Comment: Wow. Thanks! These are extremely useful examples! So the problem right now is to benchmark these to found the faster.

Comment: I tried your suggestion about `crypto/rand` but I cannot use it concurrently as you can see here: https://go.dev/play/p/CkdK1K_H_Wt. Why?

Comment: @FredHors Oh, I've read the wrong documentation, ULID is safe for concurrent access but MonotonicEntropy is not, ref: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/oklog/ulid/v2#Monotonic, the panic is due likely a corruption in internal MonotonicEntropy state because of concurrent use

Comment: Can you suggest some performant code? I found a method in this amazing post: https://qqq.ninja/blog/post/fast-threadsafe-randomness-in-go/#using-hashmaphash. Can we use it?

Comment: The package suggests that you can use any io.Reader as entropy, so yes, you can use this but you will need to get ride of ulid.Monotonic, I'm not familiar with ulid to know the implication of that, in fact if you remove the wrapper around Monotonic and use crypto.Rand directly in MustNew, the race goes away; If you want to use the maphash approach, I suggest you read the implications of its concurrent use in https://pkg.go.dev/hash/maphash@go1.18.3#Hash